# Error executing String that contains SQL sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm writing a script that runs all my databases, and check if there is a certain table in them. If this table exists, the content is divided into other tables by months.

I have reached a point where I can not continue.
The fact is that I have to generate a dynamic statement for each month, create a table, and add the data for that month to that table. This is already done, but this dynamic statement is a string and I want to execute that string to execute the SQL that it contains.

The code that does all this is the following:

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'DECLARE @FECHAInicial varchar(50) 
DECLARE @FECHAFinal varchar(50) 
DECLARE @inicio varchar(50) 
DECLARE @fin varchar(50) 
DECLARE @sql varchar(200) 
DECLARE @sql2 varchar(200)  
DECLARE @inicioMes varchar(30) 
DECLARE @finMes varchar(30)

USE ?;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=''valores'')
BEGIN
    select DB_NAME() AS [Base de datos usada];

    set @FECHAInicial = (SELECT min(fecha) from valores);
    set @FECHAFinal = (SELECT max(fecha) from valores);
    set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAInicial), "_", YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
    SET @fin = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAFinal),"_", YEAR(@FECHAFinal)));

    WHILE @inicio <> @fin
    BEGIN

        SELECT @inicio;
        set @FECHAInicial =  (SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, @FECHAInicial));
        set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAInicial), "_", YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
        set @inicioMes = (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FECHAInicial), 0))
        set @inicioMes = (select convert(varchar(30), @inicioMes, 120))
        set @finMes = DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@inicioMes) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@inicioMes), -1)
        set @finMes = DATEADD(day, 1, @finMes)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                   WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=@inicio) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT 1 AS res 
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
             -- Here is my problem
             set @sql2 = "SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' FROM valores 
                          WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('''''' + @inicioMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''') 
                          and fecha<FORMAT('''''' + @finMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''')"
             EXECUTE  @sql2
            END
    END

    IF  @inicio = @fin
    BEGIN
        SELECT @inicio
    END
END'
```

When I try to execute the SQL content of the string I skip this error

> The name 'SELECT * into dbo.'+@inicio+' FROM valores WHERE
>   fecha>=FORMAT(''' + @inicioMes + ''',''YYYY-MM-DD'') and
>   fecha

I have tried to improve the quote in some way, but I can not find the solution.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem are incorrect number of quotes. If you print your SQL statement instead of executing it, that should help you identify which quotes are incorrect. I suspect you have too many  around the date format (at least, I suspect you'll have other similar quote errors in that select due to it being a string within a string)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen i print my SQL and i get: `SELECT * into dbo.valores_6_2015 FROM valores WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('Jun  1 2015 12:00AM','YYYY-MM-DD') and fecha<FORMAT('Jul  1 2015 12:00AM','YYYY-MM-DD')`. Do you see any errors here?

Comment: Are you printed on sql Server?. Try to print this ` set @sql2 = ''SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' FROM valores WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('''''' + @inicioMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''') and fecha<FORMAT('''''' + @finMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''')''`

Comment: I would start by rewriting your sql statement as a non-dynamic string statement. Also use correct date datatype instead of concat strings. Once you have the fully working script - you can start wrapping it in strings. Your Format also gives me problems when trying to do the conversion you're doing, so there might be more issues

Comment: I just tried this with my suggested modification and it worked... Please review my answer, change your code, try it and post what you ended up with as that should work fine....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to start with double quotes and then start using single quotes....

```
"SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' 

^ double quote ---Single  ^ quotes
```

I don't think you can use the double quote in this scenario, use escaped single quotes instead.

A good idea in these cases is to print the generated sql instead of executing it, then you can see what is actually wrong. I.e. change the Execute @sql2 to Print (@Sql2) and then see what query is actually generated!

Comment: I have done what you tell me, and I have the same problem `set @sql2 = ''SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' FROM valores WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('''''' + @inicioMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''') and fecha<FORMAT('''''' + @finMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''')''`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'DECLARE @FECHAInicial varchar(50) 
DECLARE @FECHAFinal varchar(50) 
DECLARE @inicio varchar(50) 
DECLARE @fin varchar(50) 
DECLARE @sql varchar(200) 
DECLARE @sql2 varchar(200)  
DECLARE @inicioMes varchar(30) 
DECLARE @finMes varchar(30)

USE ?;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=''valores'')
BEGIN
    select DB_NAME() AS [Base de datos usada];

    set @FECHAInicial = (SELECT min(fecha) from valores);
    set @FECHAFinal = (SELECT max(fecha) from valores);
    set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT(''valores_'', MONTH(@FECHAInicial), ''_'', YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
    SET @fin = (SELECT CONCAT(''valores_'', MONTH(@FECHAFinal),''_'', YEAR(@FECHAFinal)));

    WHILE @inicio <> @fin
    BEGIN

        SELECT @inicio;
        set @FECHAInicial =  (SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, @FECHAInicial));
        set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT(''valores_'', MONTH(@FECHAInicial), ''_'', YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
        set @inicioMes = (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FECHAInicial), 0))
        set @inicioMes = (select convert(varchar(30), @inicioMes, 120))
        set @finMes = DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@inicioMes) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@inicioMes), -1)
        set @finMes = DATEADD(day, 1, @finMes)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                   WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=@inicio) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT 1 AS res 
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
             -- Here is my problem
             set @sql2 = ''SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' FROM valores 
                          WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('''''' + @inicioMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''') 
                          and fecha<FORMAT('''''' + @finMes + '''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''')''
             EXECUTE  @sql2
            END
    END

    IF  @inicio = @fin
    BEGIN
        SELECT @inicio
    END
END'
```

Comment: When it is not totally obvious you should explain what you changed to fix the problem.  Your answer may fix the OP's problem but it won't help anyone else if they can't see what you have done.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, i get the same error: `Mens. 203, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 43
The name 'SELECT * into dbo.valores_6_2015 FROM valores 
                          WHERE fecha>=FORMAT('Jun  1 2015 12:00AM','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                          and fecha<FORMAT('Jul  1 2015 12:00AM','YY' is not a valid identifier.`

Comment: Can you please post the data structure of valores  table. @PedroPérez

Comment: @RanjanaGhimire The structure is correct also, with SELECT INTO a new table is created with the same structure
My problem is when running sql2

Comment: I found your issue :
try changing sql2 varchar(200) to varchar(800)  in declaration 
@PedroPérez

Comment: I do that. I get the same error. XD. I think that is problem of my dinamic SQL

Comment: A good idea in these cases is to print the generated sql instead of executing it, then you can see what is actually wrong. I.e. change the Execute @sql2 to Print (@Sql2) and then see what query is actually generated!

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Dynamic SQL can be challenging.  As per the above answer, you probably have too many single quotes. (The first quote before select I realize is because the entire thing is a quote). In addition, I'm not sure why you need all the format commands for the dates.  If fecha is a date value, you should just be able to compare it to another date without going through all the format gyrations. Also, rather than using sp_MSforeachdb, I might suggest using a cursor over sys.databases and running the @sql2 once per row returned.  It will get rid of that extra level of quoting
IN any case, I'd break the problem apart.

1)  Instead of running this for all databases, just run the code for one database to start.

2)  Instead of using Dynamic SQL, create a properly formatted SELECT statement.  so, instead set @sql2 = 'foo' and execute @sql2, you will just have SELECT * INTO valores_Month where fecha between '2012/01/01' and '2012/01/31'

3)  When you have that working, post the simple Select statement.  And then I think it will be easier to explain the number of single quotes you need.  It may also become clear whether or not you need those formats.  As another tip, as you move from the working simple select to the dynamic SQL, don't try to get every quoted piece correct the first go. Add each quoted piece one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved my problem. It was a very simple solution

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'DECLARE @FECHAInicial varchar(50) DECLARE @FECHAFinal varchar(50) DECLARE @inicio varchar(50) DECLARE @fin varchar(50) DECLARE @sql varchar(200) DECLARE @sql2 varchar(800)  DECLARE @inicioMes varchar(30) DECLARE @finMes varchar(30)
USE ?; 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=''valores'')
BEGIN
select DB_NAME() AS [Base de datos usada];
    set @FECHAInicial = (SELECT min(fecha) from valores);
    set @FECHAFinal = (SELECT max(fecha) from valores);
    set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAInicial), "_", YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
    SET @fin = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAFinal),"_", YEAR(@FECHAFinal)));
    WHILE @inicio <> @fin
    BEGIN
        set @FECHAInicial =  (SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, @FECHAInicial));
        set @inicio = (SELECT CONCAT("valores_", MONTH(@FECHAInicial), "_", YEAR(@FECHAInicial)));
        set @inicioMes = (SELECT convert(char(10), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FECHAInicial), 0), 126))
        set @finMes = DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@inicioMes) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@inicioMes), -1)
        set @finMes = (SELECT(convert(char(10), DATEADD(day, 1, @finMes), 126)))
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME=@inicio) 
            BEGIN
            select 0
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
             set @sql2 = ''SELECT * into dbo.''+@inicio+'' FROM valores WHERE fecha>= ''''''+@inicioMes +''''''  and fecha< ''''''+ @finMes+''''''''
             select @sql2
            exec(@sql2)

            END
    END
    IF  @inicio = @fin
    BEGIN
        SELECT @inicio
    END
END'
```

Was a quotes problem. Thanks to all.